# Webpack parsing files that are neither required nor entry points

Tags: webpack

I currently have the following problem with Webpack 3:

In a big project with several entry points and hundreds of imports/requires there are a few files that are currently not used. These files are not entry points and are definitely not required in any other file.

Despite that Webpack seems to parse these files and throw errors for them (For example a missing function and the like).

Why is Webpack looking at files that are not in the dependency tree? How can I stop that behavior? Shouldn't it just look at modules that get imported, not all files in the project directory?

Thank you very much!

Comment: it seems your file imported in file that included at `entry` webpack. make sure that not `imported`. what is your target js? typescript or es2016?

Comment: I'm targeting es6. The files are not included in the entry and they are not imported anywhere, so that's why I'm confused why the typescript compiler takes a look in those files.

Comment: Check your project that have call the function, maybe call function without import